# Copying a column of strings from 2D array to 1D in google-spreadsheet-api

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm new to Javascript and the google-api and still struggling with casting and basic functionality.

I'm trying to copy a column of strings harvested from a sheet to another array for manipulation and running into various errors. So far I have tried the following ( that have not generated straight up syntax errors )...

```
// Character VALIDATION function
function validateCharacter(characterName) {
var sheetName = ("!" + characterName);
var characterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

// characterData array will hold the values from the characters sheet
var dataRange=characterSheet.getDataRange();
var characterData = dataRange.getValues();
var Physicals;
  Physicals.copyofrange(characterData,[14][0],[31][0]);
console.log(Physicals);
}
```

and

```
// Character VALIDATION function
function validateCharacter(characterName) {
var sheetName = ("!" + characterName);
var characterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

// characterData array will hold the values from the characters sheet
var dataRange=characterSheet.getDataRange();
var characterData = dataRange.getValues();
var Physicals;
for (i=0;i<17;i++){
  Physicals[i]=characterData[i+13][0];
    }
console.log(Physicals);
}
```

I know that Java handles strings as pointers, but I'm not clear if Javascript does and I thought of the for loop first but I'm getting

TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "Agile". (line 40).

when I do that. I'm assuming I'm missing something... dimensional? about the declaration of the array to be copied to but I can't figure out what. I've looked over various solutions involving Java declarations for arrays but none of those seem to apply or be allowed in the google-spreadsheets-api Javascript. It seemed to not even acknowledge the String declaration when I tried String[]=new String etc. Frankly I don't care how it's implemented just so it works. Efficiency isn't a big concern on this project. Thank you.

Comment: You're mixing everything up: Javascript, Java and Guava. Javascript is a programming language used mostly in web pages. Java is a programming language completely different and Guava is a Google library for Java. Your code is in Javascript and you speak about Java. So clarify what you want, and then we can possibly help you.

Comment: This is in the script editor on Google-spreadsheets which supposedly use Javascript with the addition of google-api functions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out. After seeing all the Java things that Javascript does not support, I found some documentation specifically on Javascript string handling and figured out I have to cast Physicals as an empty array then "push" the values into it in the loop rather than assigning them with = statements, as such.

```
// Character VALIDATION function
function validateCharacter(characterName) {
var sheetName = ("!" + characterName);
var characterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

// characterData array will hold the values from the characters sheet
var dataRange=characterSheet.getDataRange();
var characterData = dataRange.getValues();
var Physicals=[];
for (i=0;i<17;i++){
  Physicals.push(characterData[i+13][0]);
    }
return(Physicals);
}
```

Knowing the distinction between Java, Javascript, and Guava actually helped a great deal since they seem to have wildly different function handling despite similar names and common ancestry.